# Need to acquire Cinder drivers

Tags: synology, qnap, cinder

I am looking to integrate some NAS systems into Openstack, and am having some real problems.

Reading Openstack and other documentation, I know that there exist Cinder drivers for the brands of NAS that I own. The NASs I am trying to integrate are QNAP and Synology.

The problem is that all I am seeing are informational blurbs saying that the drivers exist. No one seems to be telling me where to find those drivers, what models they can be used with, or (most importantly) how to install and use them.

Does anyone have this information or any links that I can go to in order to acquire this information?

Answer (score 1):

The most recent Cinder drivers are at https://opendev.org/openstack/cinder/src/branch/master/cinder/volume/drivers. I do detect a `synology` directory. Change the Git branch from *master* to, say, *stein* for appropriate older versions.

However, when you install Cinder, you also install these drivers. They are found at $CINDER_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY/volume/drivers. No need to download them.

Driver usage is documented at https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/latest/drivers.html.